# Android: Must a Fragment's Theme be the Same as the Main Activity/App Manifest?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, themes, android-manifest

I made a new Fragment and tried to set it's theme to AppCompat.NoActionBar using Android Studio's Design tool. The problem is, once I selected it, the theme did not change and stayed on the default app theme.

After Manually Setting the theme on the Android Manifest to Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar the Fragment then accepted the Theme Change.

I want to ask the following:

Can Fragments have different Themes independent from the App Manifest or Main Activity? (Since I assume setting the Theme in the App Manifest changes it for all Activities and Fragments).

I was looking for a way to just set the Fragment's theme to AppCompat.NoActionBar but didn't get a way to do it without setting it in the App Manifest.

This is my First Question on StackOverFlow, hope it's a valid question since I couldn't find the answer online. :)

Comment: Try and include relevant code when you ask a question. Your question seems to include a lot of detail that isn't necessary for the question.

Comment: Thank you Jordan, My question isn't really code related since you change the Theme using the Design Tool from a List of Themes, so It's more of a theoretical Question than a practical coding problem.